# boost::bind equivalent in C?

Tags: c, macros

I'm looking for something similar to C++'s `boost::bind` but in C. What I want is to be able to:

```
bound_function = bind(my_function, some_param);
```

and have:

```
bound_function(something);
```

execute

```
myfunction(some_param, something);
```

So basically, whatever is bound to the function pointer will always be passed as the first parameter to the function.

Is there any way to do this in C?

Don't do this at home kids.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You couldn't do it the way C++ does it, because in `boost::bind`'s case, a class is generated using TMP that holds the actual bound value.

I'm not aware of any way to accomplish anything similar in C. Most C APIs with callbacks like this will pass around a `void *` for your use to get around issues like this.

Answer (score 2):

The closest you can get is something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef void (*function)(void*);

typedef struct {
    void *arg;
    function fn;
} binder;

binder *binder_create(function fn, void *arg) 
{
    binder *b = malloc(sizeof(binder));
    if (b) {
        b->fn = fn;
        b->arg = arg;
    }
    return b;
}

void binder_delete(binder *b)
{
    free(b);
}

void binder_exec(binder *b)
{
    b->fn(b->arg);
}

int main(void)
{
    binder *myfunc = binder_create((function)puts, "Hello, World!\n");
    binder_exec(myfunc);
    binder_delete(myfunc);
    return 0;
}
```

It doesn't give you function call like syntax (you need to call `binder_exec` instead), and you would probably need to create several versions that take more arguments and arguments of different types.

Comment: The problem is that your "bound" function is not callable like a function pointer, which negates the whole point (i.e. to bind parameters to functions so that they can be passed to APIs that expect a function pointer with the "wrong" arguments)

Comment: @Billy ONeal, the OP didn't specify that he wanted to pass the bound function to existing functions.

Answer (score 1):

In a word, no.  C has no such concept.